# What does it mean to make an interface programmatic instead of semantic?

Tags: java, c#, android, c++

At the moment I am reading the book "Code Complete, 2nd Edition". In Chapter 6.2 the author talks about classes and interfaces and gives the following advice:

> **Make interfaces programmatic rather than semantic when possible**
>   Each interface consists of a programmatic part and a semantic part.
>   The programmatic part consists of the data types and other attributes
>   of the interface that can be enforced by the compiler. The semantic
>   part of the interface consists of the assumptions about how the
>   interface will be used, which cannot be enforced by the compiler. The
>   semantic interface includes considerations such as “RoutineA must be
>   called before RoutineB” or “RoutineA will crash if dataMember1 isn’t
>   initialized before it’s passed to RoutineA.” The semantic interface
>   should be documented in comments, but try to keep interfaces minimally
>   dependent on documentation. Any aspect of an interface that can’t be
>   enforced by the compiler is an aspect that’s likely to be misused.
>   Look for ways to convert semantic interface elements to programmatic
>   interface elements by using Asserts or other techniques.

I understand what the author means by semantic and programmatic but what I don't understand is how you would convert a semantic interface function to a programmatic one. He mentions using asserts or other techniques to accomplish this.

Lets take the example of the author:

RoutineA must be Called before RoutineB. I am assuming these routines are part of the interface (public functions) because that is what this is about, ugly interfaces.

So if RoutineA must indeed be called before calling RoutineB, how would you reorganize this interface using asserts or other techniques?

I have some thoughts about this but I am not sure if they are correct.

Assuming both RoutineA and RoutineB are public functions, that would mean that both of them should be available independently of each other but the only restriction is that you first must call RoutineA before you can call RoutineB independently.

If this is indeed the case, then how would you solve this using asserts or other techniques?

If there is error in my assumption, feel free to correct me.

Also, I intentionally posted this under the current tags because tags like object-oriented-programming/design/interface have very little hits meaning my question would probably not be seen a lot.

Comment: I agree with you that this seems very bad advice. If RoutineA must be Called before RoutineB, then the correct approach would be to make them both private and create a new public RoutineC that does just that.

Comment: @DavidArno     That is indeed the first solution that came to mind in order to solve the example given by the author. But if my interpretation is correct, then you should also be able to call only RoutineB without executing the code in RoutineA but only under the restriction that you have at least called RoutineA once before calling RoutineB (maybe multiple times). After all, they are both public and it would not make any sense to have to call 2 public functions to perform one action. So maybe it would make sense to have RoutineB call RoutineA before executing its specific code.

Comment: @DavidArno That way you could call RoutineA for its own specific purpose. And you could also call RoutineB on its own as it would make the call to RoutineA on its own. This way you can use them both independantly. (this was just a brain fart though)

Comment: @DavidArno: Isn't this *exactly* McConnell's advice? Your `RoutineC` with the two others hidden in the implementation sounds like a picture-perfect example of a "programmatic interface".

Comment: @ChristianHackl The problem for me seems that both RoutineA and RoutineB are public, meaning that you should be able to call them independently but only under the restriction that A should be called first at least once.. If you made a RoutineC, then both A and B would be called everytime you called C. But that only applies if assumed that A and B have different purposes but that B is somewhat dependent on A.

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything: I think the whole point of this advice is that `RoutineA` and `RoutineB` should not be public. Other than that, I'd say the names are too generic to give you precise answers. Can you think of real-life examples in any of the languages you tagged this question with?

Comment: @ChristianHackl hmm, I cant think of anything really, haven't come across a situation like that yet,, it was more a brainfart really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible answers:

- Put `assert( a_called );` in routine `RoutineB`
- Remove `RoutineB` from the interface of the class, and make `RoutineA` return a new object which has a `RoutineB` member.

In the latter case, you probably would want to make the external classes be thin wrappers around a smart pointer to an internal class, and then `RoutineA` would just copy the pointer.

```
class Impl;
class SecondClass;
class FirstClass
{
    std::shared_ptr<Impl> pimpl;
public:
    FirstClass();
    SecondClass RoutineA(...);
    ...
}

class SecondClass
{
    std::shared_ptr<Impl> pimpl;
    friend class FirstClass;
    SecondClass(const std::shared_ptr<Impl>& impl) : pimpl(impl);
public:
    void RoutineB(....);
}

SecondClass FirstClass::RoutineA(...)
{
    // Do stuff
    return SecondClass(pimpl);
}
```

You can also do it with a `unique_ptr`, but that code is a bit longer.

Comment: I understand both points although the the last sentence does confuse me.

Comment: The second suggestion is excellent because it forces the requirement to be followed at compile time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the last paragraph either. Maybe rephrase that and/or give a concrete example? +1 for the second suggestion though.

Comment: I would like that very much aswell! Im kind of intrigued by the 2nd solution wootwoot

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the restriction ("RoutineA must be Called before RoutineB") at run time. Programming languages in the tags cannot check such a restriction at compile time.
Your code may look like:

```
RoutineA()
{
  aCalled = true;
  //some operations..
}
RoutineB()
{
  if(!aCalled) // or an assertion
  {
    throw NotReadyException("RoutineA must be called");
  }
  //some operations..
}
```

Comment: @Q Q           I voted Martin Bonners answer as the correct one because he gave more than one solution. And the other solution is even better because with the boolean check, RoutineB is dependent on RoutineA. Meaning you would have to handle the exception correctly if someone indeed called only RoutineA. The answer Martin Bonner gives ensures that RoutineB can only be accessed after calling RoutineA.

Comment: You are right. Bonners came with an inteligent solution. Nevertheless, let's consider a real life example: You should open a file first, then you can read/write. So according to Bonners you should define a `File` class which has an `open()` method. `open()` returns a `FileStream` object. Obviously, you can read/write using this object. What about close? ,`FileStream` may have a `close()` method. But it doesn't match with the `open()` method in the `File` class. This situation indicates a design problem. So, I mean that it is difficult to generalize this elegant but specific solution.

Comment: @Q Q           hmmm indeed, that would be a big problem! Throwing an exception would be much better in this case.